# Setting margin causes ionic view become scrollable

Tags: css, ionic-framework

This is the initial code that I have. And it does not have scrollbar. Note that the text here is a paragraph of text, where it will be scrollable when the content is greater than the view. Currently, since the text does not exceed the view height, the scrollbar is not available.

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <div>
        <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I need to make some modification to the code, where there should be some margin above the text here.

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
    <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
        <p>Text here</p>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

After i make the above modification, the content become scrollable (and you can see that there is scrollbar becomes available).

Am i doing anything wrong? Or what can i do to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of the issue. ?

Comment: add `overflow:scroll` to content that you are trying to have scroll.

Answer (score 0):

ion-scroll to be used.This worked for me:

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
        <div style="margin-top: 20px;">
          <ion-scroll direction="y" style= "height:60px;">
            <p>Long Text</p>
          </ion-scroll>
        </div>
</ion-content>
```